# Liquibase slows down unit tests

Tags: spring, liquibase

Our project has over 500 test suites. It takes up to 30 mins to run and I found a huge amount of time spending is on Liquibase when initializing Spring context for test suite.

Would like to know if there are any good approach to accelerate the process? E.g. Run Liquibase one time and do file copy (h2 database) to reset database for each test suite?

Comment: What do you think takes all the time? Is it creating lots of tables/test data/indexes or just the amount of times the db gets initialised? You could possibly use liquibase profiles to reduce the amount of initialization required for different test suites, though I imagine your suggestion of copying an initialized database files would work.

Comment: Are you using same context for all test or you spin a new context for each test? If the latest is the option, you should re-think your test architecture. We have ~300 tests and it takes 3-4 minutes.

Comment: @bilak yes we spin up new spring text context for each test suite (not test case). What's your opinion on test architecture?

Comment: well in that case I'd reuse the context. why do you spin it up every time? because of data that are causing issues in each test? truncating tables before each test/test case may be faster than spinning up whole spring context.